# Kubernetes: How to force kube-proxy to listen on localhost only

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

In my configuration, very basic one (Only calico network, no apps yet)
I have nginx-ingress running as NodePort - binding on port 30080. This port should be accessible only from localhost, but k8s opened this port for everyone, and since it's binding on 0.0.0.0 it's wide open now.

So I want to force kube-proxy to bind this port to 127.0.0.1 only.

I've tried modifing configmap to nginx-ingress (bind-address) but no luck with that.

Since this port is attached to kube-proxy - i was looking for kube-proxy config, but no luck at all.
I've found yaml config file in /var/lib/kube-proxy but modifing it didn't change this.

After restarting pods, they are still binded to 0.0.0.0

I've tried many ways from internet, but still no luck.

Cluster was initialised with:
kubeadm init  --pod-network-cidr=10.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX --apiserver-advertise-address=X.X.X.X

Comment: You changed configmap to nginx-ingress. Did you try to change kube-proxy configmap? `kubectl edit cm kube-proxy -n kube-system`?

Comment: Well It looks like this is the thing. I've changed bindaddress to 127.0.0.1 but it didn't work. Everything looks the same. I've tried deleting kube-proxy pods, and even whole machine, but it still is the same. ConfigMap seems to be ok, but not read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you have been looking for however this way, it will listen on `127.0.0.1:NodePort`

You need to change `kube-proxy` [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) but not `bindAddress:` (it should be left as it was `bindAddress: 0.0.0.0`) and default value `nodePortAddresses: null` should be changed to `nodePortAddresses: ["127.0.0.0/8"]`. It must be `["127.0.0.0/8"]` as if you will change just to `127.0.0.1/8` `kube-proxy` pod will crush.

Change `nodePortAddresses: null` to `nodePortAddresses: ["127.0.0.0/8"]` and save using `:wq`. As default `edit` will open in `VI` text editor.

```
$ kubectl edit cm kube-proxy -n kube-system
configmap/kube-proxy edited
```

If you would like use nano as text editor you must use `KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit cm kube-proxy -n kube-system`.

As example i have used `Nginx deployment` from [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/). Only chage was add `type: NodePort` to service YAML.

Now you will need to apply this new configuration to kube-proxy. Easiest way is to delete `kube-proxy` pod as `daemonset.apps/kube-proxy` will create new one with new config.

**Original output:**

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        19m
my-nginx     NodePort    10.109.237.94   <none>        80:31672/TCP   24s
$ netstat -plnt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
...
```

**Output with changed `nodePortAddresses:`**

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        33m
my-nginx     NodePort    10.96.27.244   <none>        80:30679/TCP   2m40s
$ netstat -plnt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30679         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
...
```

Comment: Thank You! My issue is solved!

Comment: How the settings are changed will depend on the flavour of Kubernetes. I'm using microk8s, and I had to edit `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-proxy` and add `--nodeport-addresses=127.0.0.0/8`. This answer got me 90% of the way though so thanks!